# Plays SettingsAPI - Is there way to request only GPS turned on or only WIFI Turned On?

Tags: android, google-play-services

During resolution, SettingAPI will present dialog, but it contains everything that it detects the user needs to activate.  For example, WIFI and GPS.  I would like to prompt the user to turn on only GPS for example, but not WIFI for security reasons.  If I send them to settings instead of the using Plays ,new Settings API they have the option of turning everything on.  I am trying to limit to just one type of setting and I would like to use the SettingAPI dialog for this.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet here is not to add the
***android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE*** permission. 
This way the app won't have any information about Wi-Fi Networks.

But do add the 
***android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION*** and ***android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION*** in the Manifest file so that the app can always look for the GPS.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Any way to remove permissions within code? so this selection can be dynamic? Sometimes WIFI, sometimes GPS?

Comment: It's Google Play Services that access Wi-Fi scans, not your app. You can still get network location from Google Play Services even your app doesn't have Wi-Fi-related permissions.

Answer (score 0):

SettingsApi doesn't allow you to specify location providers directly (GPS location, network location provider, etc). Instead, you can only ask for [location priorities](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setPriority(int)), and SettingsApi chooses location providers for you.

As there's no GPS-only location priority, you can't request that you only need to turn on GPS, but leave network location off. You can request for network-only location mode by setting your location priority to either `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` or `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER`.